# Exit a callback method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, callback, cordova-plugins

Issue : I am using Cognex MX-1000 to scan barcodes. I have three textboxes and I am trying to scan barcodes and change the focus to next textbox. But after I scan the third textbox the value is always entered in third textbox even when the focus is on first textbox.

Cause : My code is not able to exit the innermost Setresultcallback function. Below is my method does anyone know how to exit the innermost callback function?

```
 me.scanner.setResultCallback(function (result) {  //First callback
        var barcode = result.readString;
        var txt1 = barcode;
        document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = txt1;
        document.getElementById("TextBox2").focus();

        me.scanner.setResultCallback(function (result) {  //Second callback
            var barcode = result.readString;
            var txt2 = barcode;
            document.getElementById("TextBox2").value = txt2;
            document.getElementById("TextBox3").focus();

            me.scanner.setResultCallback(function (result) {   //Third Callback & stuck here!!! I want to exit this function
                var barcode = result.readString;
                var txt3 = barcode;
                document.getElementById("TextBox3").value = txt3;
                document.getElementById("TextBox1").focus();
                return;
            });
            return;
        });
        return;
    });
```

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the question, you set the value in the third field manually: `document.getElementById("TextRec3").value = txt3;`

Comment: txt3 is the barcode read from the scanner.

Comment: Right, but you're targetting `TextRec3`, which would logically indicate it's the third field that you state shouldn't have the value.

Comment: The problem is once the 3rd field is filled in it doesn't rap back around to the first one on the next scan.

Comment: @Roy McCrossan It should capture the value on third textbox and then on the next scan the value should be entered in first textbox since the focus is moved to first but after third scan it always scans value on the third textbox.

Comment: @Feathercrown You are right but how to fix it ?

Comment: This seems like you should have something that has a "result,currentitem,nextItem" passed in that is the callback rather than nested callbacks

Comment: @Programmermid It seems like you got 3 different good answers to your question, each with different methods. Guess that answers that! ;)

Comment: @Feathercrown Yea thats true how often does that happen lol. I got lucky today thanks to you guys.

Comment: @Programmermid Yeah it's pretty anomalous. Anyways, I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you leave the callback for the third field in the last callback. The following should fix the problem.

```
me.scanner.setResultCallback(/* Change here -> */ function firstFieldCallback(result) {  //First callback
        var barcode = result.readString;
        var txt1 = barcode;
        document.getElementById("TextRec1").value = txt1;
        document.getElementById("TextRec2").focus();

        me.scanner.setResultCallback(function (result) {  //Second callback
            var barcode = result.readString;
            var txt2 = barcode;
            document.getElementById("TextRec2").value = txt2;
            document.getElementById("TextRec3").focus();

            me.scanner.setResultCallback(function (result) {   //Third Callback & stuck here!!! I want to exit this function
                var barcode = result.readString;
                var txt3 = barcode;
                document.getElementById("TextRec3").value = txt3;
                document.getElementById("TextRec1").focus();

                /* Change here -> */ me.scanner.setResultCallback(firstFieldCallback);                  

                return;
            });
            return;
        });
        return;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Man This fixed my issue. Let me know where you want me to send you a pack of beer lol.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't rebind to your first callback. Since you always do the same things into your callbacks :

1. Get the value
2. Write the value to the current input
3. Focus the next input

It can be simplified to something like this :

```js
var me = {
    scanner: {
      setResultCallback: function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          callback({
            readString: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
          })
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
  },
  textboxes = ['TextRec1', 'TextRec2', 'TextRec3'],
  index = 0;

function readValue(result) {
  var barcode = result.readString;

  document.getElementById(textboxes[index++]).value = barcode;

  index = index === textboxes.length ? 0 : index;
  document.getElementById(textboxes[index]).focus();

  me.scanner.setResultCallback(readValue);
}

me.scanner.setResultCallback(readValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="TextRec1" />
<input type="text" id="TextRec2" />
<input type="text" id="TextRec3" />
```

Don't mind `var me = { ...` I wanted something to simulate the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Wow, we have almost the exact same output box, even with different methods. Weird.

Comment: @Feathercrown the HTML is the same, though ;)

Comment: True, but even the setInterval with a 1-second timeout and setting up the object and stuff is the same, even with the different methods.

Comment: @Serge This also worked thanks. But I marked Bsalex's as answer because I will have to make less changes in my code everywhere since its aligned with my current logic. Thanks though!

Comment: Plus for having only one function to maintain and adding to the array makes it easily extended

Answer (score 1):

I've made a snippet to demonstrate how this can be done. Each function sets the callback to an existing function rather than creating a new one to set it to. I got it working with setInterval so you can see what's happening better; you can see that each new scan scan overwrites the next box, proving that the focus wraps around.

```js
//Code to make this work in a snippet
var me = {};
me.scanner={};
me.scanner.setResultCallback = function(newcallback){scancallback=newcallback;};

//Set the callback to the first function; each function sets it to the next
me.scanner.setResultCallback(scan1);

//Simulate scanning stuff by manually calling the callback with time intervals; just pretend each time the function is called, it's called naturally by scanning with the scanner
setInterval(function(){
  scancallback({randomField:"this is a scan result I guess",readString:Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)});
},1000);

function scan1(scanresult){
  //Don't even need the variables, if you need them somehow you can add them back
  document.getElementById("TextRec1").value = 
scanresult.readString;
  document.getElementById("TextRec2").focus();
  me.scanner.setResultCallback(scan2);
}

function scan2(scanresult){
  //Don't even need the variables, if you need them somehow you can add them back
  document.getElementById("TextRec2").value = 
scanresult.readString;
  document.getElementById("TextRec3").focus();
  me.scanner.setResultCallback(scan3);
}

function scan3(scanresult){
  //Don't even need the variables, if you need them somehow you can add them back
  document.getElementById("TextRec3").value = 
scanresult.readString;
  document.getElementById("TextRec1").focus();
  me.scanner.setResultCallback(scan1);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="TextRec1"/>
<input type="text" id="TextRec2"/>
<input type="text" id="TextRec3"/>
```